# Mypy: all strings except specific value

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

```
@overload
def build(param: Literal["some_value"], **kwargs) -> "A": ...

@overload
def build(param: str, **kwargs) -> "B": ...
```

In short, build() returns "A" if the param equals "value", else it returns "B". How can I type hint this?

MyPy doesn't like this and claims the signatures are overlapping with incompatible return types.

Comment: The only value you can treat as a type is `None`;  a return type of `"A"` is invalid, not indicating that it returns the value `"A"`. Also, `Literal` means a literal in the source code; for `build`, `x = "some_value"; build(x)` and `build("some_value")` are treated differently.

Comment: Despite having a case with `Literal["some_value"]`, `str` is still capable of matching the sting `"some_value"`. If you use `Literal` in one case, there's no way to specify "anything except one or more specific values" in another as a catch-all.

Comment: You are being so specific here that there's little point in returning *any* value. If you know you are passing `some_value` as the argument, you can simply assume a value `"A"` instead of needing `build` to return it to you. Basically, you are straying out of the realm of static type checking, at least in regard to the kind of types that Python type checkers support. (Specifically, you are missing support for dependent types.)

Comment: The examples A and B were just that, examples. You can replace them with anything you want. The question is about whether it's possible to have this kind of overloading. As for the remarks on Literal, that's again not the point. I want to be able to tell MyPy that "B" or whatever is being returned for anything that's not "some_value".

Comment: Python's type system does not support the constructs you need to turn this kind of constraint into a type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to split it like that. Why? Because it would suggest a false dichotomy between a literal argument and a variable one.

Let's check the following definition:

```
def build(param: Literal["some_value"], **kwargs) -> Literal["A"]:
    if param == "some_value":
        return "A"
x = "some_value"
build(x) # returns "A", but raises MyPy error

build("some_value") #returns "A" with no error
```

MyPy raises an error stating: `Argument 1 to "build" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Literal['some_value']"`. This is expected. We're supposed to call it like `build("some_value")`. But at runtime, this would be handled just the same, because in both cases `param` is set to `"some_value"` inside the function.
Ok, now let's try to implement handling any other value for param (no type-hinting for now)

```
def build(param, **kwargs):
    if param == "some_value":
        return "A"
    else:
        return "B"
```

Now, we obviously expect both of these calls to return `"A"`:

```
x = "some_value"
build(x)

build("some_value")
```

But if you consider the previously mentioned error, `build(x)` would match `param: str` typing, not `Literal["some_value"]`, which means according to your typing it should return `"B"`. Which is of course a ridiculous behaviour for a function.

Taking all of these into account, I think your function signature should look like this:

```
def build(param: str, **kwargs) -> Literal["B"] | Literal["A"]: ...
```